# Remote Mysql drop all connections and allow only localhost and IP address

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, remote-access, iptables

I have enabled remote MySQL by editing

```
 /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf 
    bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Now i can access MySQL via any remote ip.

What i want is to disable all connections to my MySQL with IP tables and enable only access from localhost and one IP adress. I did the following

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 16x.xxx.xx.xx --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

The following code will drop all connections and won't accept localhost or remote ip. I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 .

---

**EDIT:** I've also tried a chain

```
iptables -N mysql 
iptables -A mysql --src 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A mysql --src 14x.xxx.xx.xx -j ACCEPT
iptables -A mysql -j DROP 
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j mysql
```

After DROP line in every possible way port is blocked

Answer (score 1):

The order of the rules is not correct.

Line

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

should come last.

Comment: (110 "Connection timed out") I tryed that before also and it won't work. It will still drop all connections and port is blocked then

Comment: Could you please paste here output of the iptables-save  command.

Comment: Rijeka here @Marko help out :D

Comment: :) 
Temporary flush all rules and test again. If it still doesn't work, something on a route is blocking you.

Comment: If it does work, then you have whitelisted a wrong IP address.

Comment: Tested many times with both firewall and ip tables. Triple checked IP address and all looks fine. But again won't work as soon as i add 3306 DROP

Comment: I was completely blind, the rules are not correct.  The  **-d** means  destination. Put  **-s**  instead .

Comment: /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 144.xx.xx.xx --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT

Comment: And as soon as i add iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP port is blocked for all

Comment: root@server-1:/home/ubuntu# iptables -L -n --line-number
   Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            tcp dpt:3306
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  14x.xxx.xxx.xx       14x.xxx.xxx.xx       tcp dpt:3306
3    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Answer (score 0):

The rule

```
2 ACCEPT tcp -- 14x.xxx.xxx.xx 14x.xxx.xxx.xx tcp dpt:3306
```

doesn't look right. It looks like source and destination IP addresses are the same. You have to whitelist the IP address of the server which you are connecting from.

In order to identify IP address add the following iptables rule before the drop rule

```
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306  -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Mysql access log: "
```

The log goes in dmesg and syslog ( /var/log/syslog on Ubuntu) and looks like this

```
Nov 28 08:55:57 myServer kernel: Mysql access log: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:19:99:ce:15:cb:b0:c6:9a:67:d6:81:08:00 SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=5.6.7.8 LEN=60 TOS=0x10  PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=63880 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40807 DPT=3306 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

In my example source ip address which should be whitelisted is 1.2.3.4

Comment: ACCEPT     tcp  --  144.xx.xx.xx       213..xx.xx.xx         tcp dpt:3306
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  144..xx.xx.xx       127.0.0.1            tcp dpt:3306
    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306                I did as you said but still it won't work SRC=144.xx.xx.xx DST=213.xx.xx.xx LEN=54 TOS=0x02 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=7163 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62891 DPT=3306 W$